# Get all the text in front of the last character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the path up to the last character \ in the below file path.

```
C:\test\test1\V1000\20\7783456\7783456_p0000.tif
```

The output should be "C:\test\test1\V1000\20\7783456"

What is wrong with the below script? It is printing only up to certain characters.

```
DECLARE @FullPath VARCHAR(500)
SET @FullPath =
  'C:\test\test1\V1000\20\7783456\7783456_p0000.tif'

SELECT LEFT(@FullPath , CHARINDEX ('\' ,REVERSE(@FullPath))-1)
```

Comment: `Left` is measuring from the _start_ of the string. When you apply `CharIndex` to the result of `Reverse` you are measuring from the _end_ of the string. As Patrick Hurst's answer shows, you need to correct the offset back to the start of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REVERSE` can be useful in these situations:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (FullPath VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @Table (FullPath) VALUES ('C:\test\test1\V1000\20\7783456\7783456_p0000.tif');

SELECT *, LEFT(FullPath,LEN(FullPath)-CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(FullPath)))
  FROM @Table;
```

We reverse the string, and then look for the first occurrence. Subtract that from the length, and you find the character before the character prior to the last occurence.